# Do you need an "output" to express a dependency on a resource in a terraform module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Can you depend on a resource id within a module without first defining it as an output of that module?

I have a terraform project with a bunch of elements defined at the top level for now. I've put security groups into a module, as they're pretty verbose (when using `aws_security_group_rule`), and since I really only need the IDs elsewhere in the project.

So, I imagine I have a top-level terraform file like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example_instance" {
    # instance config goes here
    vpc_security_group_ids = [
        "${reference}",
    ]
}
```

And a configuration in a `security_groups` module like:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "example_group" {
    # security group config goes here
}
```

Can the reference in the first file be anything like "${module.security_groups.example_group.id}"? Near as I can tell, the answer is no, I get errors like:

```
* module root:
    resource 'aws_instance.example_instance' config: 
    aws_security_group.example_group.id is not a valid output for
    module security_groups
```

However, I haven't found this explicitly documented anywhere, so I'm trying to confirm my understanding.  The only way I can find that works is to do something like this in the module file:

```
output "example_group_id" {
    value = "${aws_security_group.example_group.id}"
}
```

And then the reference goes like this: `${module.security_groups.example_group_id}`

So, can anyone confirm (and ideally point to documentation that confirms) that's the right way to do it, with an output? Or, alternately, tell me how to do it without an output?

Comment: Yes and it is obvious, you need set output for the module, otherwise, it can't be referenced.

Comment: Yes. The module is like a black box to the caller. The caller can only reference the output variables.

Comment: @BMW I'm glad it's obvious to you -- it wasn't clear to me. The only place I can find that even suggests it is "Modules can also specify their own outputs. These outputs can be referenced in other places in your configuration, for example:", which definitely suggests that if you want to reference the content of a module, you need an output, but nothing I can find actually says that. Anyway, thanks for confirming, both of you, although neither of you made an answer, so I can't accept it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need set output for that module, otherwise, it can't be referenced.

Terraform is open source project (there are enterprise version as well, it is not open sourced.). If you think the `output` document is not good enough, please raise pull request to update it.

The related markdown document is here:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/website/docs/configuration/outputs.html.md

Comment: Incidentally, I contributed a small clarification to the documentation on this point after having this discussion:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/15930

It's small, but maybe will help others in the future.